# Linux networking using macvlan interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, nas, bridge

This setup is working for my needs but I don't understand it which concerns me e.g I assume it's possible a system update could break this functionality and if I don't properly understand then how can I repair/restore it. Also I'm open to better/proper ways of working so welcome any insights learnt here.

This is about linux networking, macvlan interfaces and yes ultimately docker containers but I'm more concerned with the OS networking and the layer 2/3 outcomes I have. My host is a Synology DS1019+ NAS.

Using config files placed in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ I can create a new br0 interface against eth0. The mac of the new br0 interface is the same as the eth0 interface. In this configuration I no longer have an IPv4 against eth0, only br0 has an address and is routable on my subnet. My current understanding is that the above is sound and as expected.

Its my understanding as above which is what is calling me to question the next part.

Instead of using config files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ I have instead used the linux ip command to achieve a similar outcome.

```
ip link add link eth0 name br0 type macvlan mode bridge
```

After reading a number of other articles proposing this method I now have an IPv4 address against **both** the linked eth0 (physical) interface as well as an address on the newly created br0 interface and br0 has an entirely unique mac address of its own. To be clear the subnets on each interface are different. Both interfaces work, I can reach them on the host as well as from remote devices in my lan, the only additional step for remote devices was the placement of a static route on my router pointing back towards my nas for the new br0 subnet.

I don't understand how eth0 still has an IPv4 address and I don't understand how br0 has its own unique mac address given my expectations of the command and it being a macvlan bridge.

My interface layout before modification...

eth0: 192.168.1.0/24, eth1: disconnected

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000    
    link/ether 00:11:32:c0:fb:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.5/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::211:32ff:fec0:fb37/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:32:c0:fb:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.6.42/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000    
    link/ether 02:42:ad:6c:d4:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:adff:fe6c:d47f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I issue 3 commands as below to create br0 and place it in a seperate subnet...

```
ip link add link eth0 name br0 type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 192.168.10.1/24 dev br0
ip link set br0 up
```

Which then changes my interface layout to be...

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000    
    link/ether 00:11:32:c0:fb:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.5/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::211:32ff:fec0:fb37/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:32:c0:fb:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.6.42/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br0@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/ether 76:31:e6:37:27:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.1/24 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7431:e6ff:fe37:2797/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000    
    link/ether 02:42:ad:6c:d4:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:adff:fe6c:d47f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I note the "state UNKNOWN" for the br0 interface however it does work!

Comment: Your opening paragraph is confusing. The use of 'aka' feels like you probably mean e.g. 'for example' not a.k.a 'also known as' but then lack of punctuation makes it unclear whether it's the updates you don't understand, or the breakage; or what that may actually entail.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin, made some edits to hopefully my clearer.